# How to set font size of Matplotlib axis Legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size, legend

I have a code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('xx-small')
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
ax1.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
           prop = fontP,fancybox=True,shadow=False,title='LEGEND')
plt.show()
```

[image: legend fontsize]

It can be seen in the plot that the setting in Fontsize does not affect the Legend Title font size.

How to set the font size of the legend title to a smaller size?

Comment: For an updated (2021), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67879275/2612410

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is definitely an old question, but was frustrating me too and none of the other answers changed the legend *title* fontsize at all, but instead just changed the rest of the text. So after banging my head against the matplotlib documentation for awhile I came up with this.

```
legend = ax1.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
           prop = fontP,fancybox=True,shadow=False,title='LEGEND')

plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize='xx-small')
```

As of Matplotlib 3.0.3, you can also set it globally with

```
plt.rcParams['legend.title_fontsize'] = 'xx-small'
```

Comment: `title_fontsize` is now an argument you can pass to `legend(...)`, but your answer made it discoverable for me, so thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Here is how to change the fontsize of the legend list and/or legend title:

```
legend=plt.legend(list,loc=(1.05,0.05), title=r'$\bf{Title}$') #Legend: list, location, Title (in bold)
legend.get_title().set_fontsize('6') #legend 'Title' fontsize
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='12') #legend 'list' fontsize
```

Comment: Can you please help me in merging the code piece you have proposed with mine? I'm seeing some errors when I add this piece to the code I have.
Specifically:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 <file>  in <module>
    legend=plt.legend(list,loc=(1.05,0.05), title=r'$\bf{Title}$') #Legend: list, location, Title (in bold)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2800, in legend
    ret =  gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4494, in legend
    labels)]
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Comment: I've noticed these commands do not work in Spyder using the IPython console but work well in a standard python (v2.7) console. In IPython it gives 'NameError: name 'gca' is not defined' .

Answer (score 35):

Banged my head against it too, here is another more flowing way of doing it:

```
leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_title('A great legend',prop={'size':14})
```

Answer (score 35):

Inspired by the current top answer, I found a slightly more natural way to change the fontsizes in the legend. The `fontsize` argument sets the font size of each of the data labels, and the `title_fontsize` argument sets the fontsize of the title, if you give the legend a title.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,2],[2,1,2],label='test_data (fs=12)')
ax.legend(fontsize=12, title='TITLE (fs=30)',title_fontsize=30)
```

Gives a figure like this:
[image]

Comment: this fails if custom lines/patches have been added

Comment: This should be the leading answer

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how to set it up for an individual plot, but I always do it globally:

```
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':6})
```

Answer (score 13):

Now in 2021, with matplotlib 3.4.2 you can set your legend fonts with

```
plt.legend(title="My Title", fontsize=10, title_fontsize=15)
```

where `fontsize` is the font size of the items in legend and `title_fontsize` is the font size of the legend title. More information in [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Answer (score 7):

This is the fastest:

```
plt.legend(loc=2,prop={'size':6})
```

Comment: This one doesn't change the title size unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I generally do in this way. Once the plot has been done i do the following

```
plt.legend(loc=0, numpoints=1)
leg = plt.gca().get_legend()
ltext  = leg.get_texts()
plt.setp(ltext, fontsize='small')
```

I don't know if this works for you

Comment: In ipython notebook, I just do `setp(gca().get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='small')`.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy method is using (it served me)

```
ax.legend(title = "anything", title_fontsize = 8, fontsize = 6)
```

title_fontsize is useful for changing the fontsize of the title

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).