# How do I set the figure title and axes labels font size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, yaxis, x-axis

I am creating a figure in Matplotlib like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)
fig.suptitle('test title')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
fig.savefig('test.jpg')
```

I want to specify font sizes for the figure title and the axis labels. I need all three to be different font sizes, so setting a global font size (`mpl.rcParams['font.size']=x`) is not what I want. How do I set font sizes for the figure title and the axis labels individually?

Answer (score 1239, accepted):

Functions dealing with text like `label`, `title`, etc. accept parameters same as [`matplotlib.text.Text`](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html). For the font size you can use `size/fontsize`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(data)
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)
fig.savefig('test.jpg')
```

For globally setting `title` and `label` sizes, [`mpl.rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) contains `axes.titlesize` and `axes.labelsize`. (From the page):

```
axes.titlesize      : large   # fontsize of the axes title
axes.labelsize      : medium  # fontsize of the x any y labels
```

(As far as I can see, there is no way to set `x` and `y` label sizes separately.)

And I see that `axes.titlesize` does not affect `suptitle`. I guess, you need to set that manually.

Comment: thanks!  is there a way to set that globally but explicitly for (suptitle, xlabel, ylabel)?  I am making a lot of charts and just want to specify it once...

Comment: @vasek1: I thought you didn't want global setting :). For that you need `mpl.rcParams`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: To anyone else like myself looking for the solution to change the titlesize: `plt.rcParams.update({'axes.titlesize': 'small'})`

Comment: From the `rcParams` link, use `figure.titlesize` in addition to `axes.titlesize`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `u'figure.titlesize is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'` ... Don't think it works although it is listed strangely enough

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane. I ran `python -c 'import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.__version__); print("figure.titlesize" in mpl.rcParams.keys())'`. Result is `1.5.1`, `True`. 1) What version of matplotlib are you using? What version of Python? 2) Could it be a bug where for some reason it accepts `str` but not `unicode` in Py2?

Comment: `python: 2.7.11` and `matplotlib: 1.4.3` ... I hate these sorts of bugs they're so pedantic to figure out especially when we have lots of interesting physics to plot! I will just leave it here as a warning in case someone thinks they've done it wrong

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to globally set explicit numeric sizes for the title and the axis-labels instead of always doing `ax.set_title('some title', fontsize=15)`, `ax.set_xlabel('some xlabel', fontsize=12)`? It seems like `rcParams` only accepts strings.

Comment: it seems this approach is no longer recommended by the documentation? Could the obj oriented approach be added too?

Comment: For reasons unknown, when I used this solution "horizontalalignment='center'" did not work for my title. I ended up using "ax.set_title()" as a final solution.

Answer (score 152):

You can also do this globally via a rcParams dictionary:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'x-large',
          'figure.figsize': (15, 5),
         'axes.labelsize': 'x-large',
         'axes.titlesize':'x-large',
         'xtick.labelsize':'x-large',
         'ytick.labelsize':'x-large'}
pylab.rcParams.update(params)
```

Comment: What are other sizes besides `'x-large'`?

Comment: ‘xx-small’, ‘x-small’, ‘small’, ‘medium’, ‘large’, ‘x-large’, ‘xx-large’. See https://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties.set_size

Comment: Use `pylab.rcParams.keys()` to see the full list of parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to globally set explicit numeric sizes for the title and the axis-labels instead of always doing `ax.set_title('some title', fontsize=15)`, `ax.set_xlabel('some xlabel', fontsize=12)`? It seems like `rcParams` only accepts strings.

Comment: You can also use numbers... `'axes.labelsize': 32,`

Comment: In addition to `axes.titlesize`, you have this guy `{'figure.titlesize':'medium'}`, who can be reached at (say) `plt.suptitle("SUP", y=0.95)`, where the  `y` parameter can be useful.

Answer (score 141):

If you're more used to using `ax` objects to do your plotting, you might find the `ax.xaxis.label.set_size()` easier to remember, or at least easier to find using tab in an ipython terminal. It seems to need a redraw operation after to see the effect. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set up a plot with dummy data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [0, 3, 9]
ax.plot(x,y)

# title and labels, setting initial sizes
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', fontsize='medium')   # relative to plt.rcParams['font.size']

# setting label sizes after creation
ax.xaxis.label.set_size(20)
plt.draw()
```

I don't know of a similar way to set the suptitle size after it's created.

Comment: `fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize = 20)` seems to work. `ax.set_xlabel('xlabel', fontsize = 20)' also works, in which case we can do away with `ax.xaxis.label.set_size(20)`.

Comment: @T_T That's true, and these forms are similar to Avaris' answer above. I'll add them for completeness. I still find a use for `ax.xaxis.label.set_size()` when I'm working interactively with an _ipython_ plot and I want to do a quick visual assessment of a variety of font sizes.

Comment: Do you know if there's any (hidden) difference between using ax objects and figure objects, or are both perfectly equivalent? Why are there different interfaces for some of the features? (plt.xlabel() vs. ax.set_xlabel())

Comment: @normanius, if you mean ax and fig in the above example, they are quite different objects -- fig is the overall figure, which may contain several axes. So fig and ax have different properties. In terms of the difference between the pyplot type calls and object calls (e.g.  `plt.xlabel()` vs. `ax.set_xlabel()` as you say), they are equivalent, with the caveat that the `plt.*` functions work on the _current_ axis/figure. So it you set up a figure with multiple axes, you'll probably want to use explicit calls like `ax1.set_xlabel()` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 56):

To only modify the title's font (and not the font of the axis) I used this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('My Title', fontdict={'fontsize': 8, 'fontweight': 'medium'})
```

The fontdict accepts all kwargs from [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text).

Comment: I'm running Python 3.8.5 and I don't need to use ```fontdict```. It does work, but you can also use:
```ax.set_title("My Title", fontsize=18, fontwieght="medium")```. This also works on ```ax2.set_xticklabels``` etc.

Answer (score 48):

> Per [the official guide](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related), use of `pylab` is no longer recommended. `matplotlib.pyplot` should be used directly instead.

Globally setting font sizes via `rcParams` should be done with

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 16

# or

params = {'axes.labelsize': 16,
          'axes.titlesize': 16}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

# or

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=16, titlesize=16)

# or 

axes = {'labelsize': 16,
        'titlesize': 16}
mpl.rc('axes', **axes)
```

The defaults can be restored using

```py
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
```

You can also do this by creating a [style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#using-style-sheets) in the `stylelib` directory under the [matplotlib configuration directory](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations) (you can get your configuration directory from `matplotlib.get_configdir()`). The style sheet format is

```
axes.labelsize: 16
axes.titlesize: 16
```

If you have a style sheet at `/path/to/mpl_configdir/stylelib/mystyle.mplstyle` then you can use it via

```py
plt.style.use('mystyle')

# or, for a single section

with plt.style.context('mystyle'):
    # ...
```

You can also create (or modify) a [matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) which shares the format

```
axes.labelsize = 16
axes.titlesize = 16
```

Depending on which matplotlibrc file you modify these changes will be used for only the current working directory, for all working directories which do **not** have a matplotlibrc file, or for all working directories which do **not** have a matplotlibrc file and where no other matplotlibrc file has been specified. See [this section](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) of the customizing matplotlib page for more details.

A complete list of the `rcParams` keys can be retrieved via `plt.rcParams.keys()`, but for adjusting font sizes you have (italics quoted from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file))

- `axes.labelsize` - *Fontsize of the x and y labels*
- `axes.titlesize` - *Fontsize of the axes title*
- `figure.titlesize` - *Size of the figure title (`Figure.suptitle()`)*
- `xtick.labelsize` - *Fontsize of the tick labels*
- `ytick.labelsize` - *Fontsize of the tick labels*
- `legend.fontsize` - Fontsize for legends (`plt.legend()`, `fig.legend()`)
- `legend.title_fontsize` - Fontsize for legend titles, *`None` sets to the same as the default axes.* See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402561/how-to-set-font-size-of-matplotlib-axis-legend/17093475#17093475) for usage example.

all of which accept string sizes `{'xx-small', 'x-small', 'smaller', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'larger', 'x-large', 'xxlarge'}` or a `float` in `pt`. The string sizes are defined relative to the default font size which is specified by

- `font.size` - *the default font size for text, given in pts. 10 pt is the standard value*

Additionally, the weight can be specified (though only for the default it appears) by

- `font.weight` - The default weight of the font used by `text.Text`. Accepts `{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900}` or `'normal'` (400), `'bold'` (700), `'lighter'`, and `'bolder'` (*relative with respect to current weight*).

Answer (score 23):

If you aren't explicitly creating figure and axis objects you can set the title fontsize when you create the title with the `fontdict` argument.

You can set and the x and y label fontsizes separately when you create the x and y labels with the `fontsize` argument.

For example:

```py
plt.title('Car Prices are Increasing', fontdict={'fontsize':20})
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Price', fontsize=16)
```

Works with seaborn and pandas plotting (when Matplotlib is the backend), too!

Answer (score 17):

Others have provided answers for how to change the title size, but as for the axes tick label size, you can also use the [set_tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) method.

E.g., to make the x-axis tick label size small:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize='small')
```

or, to make the y-axis tick label large:

```
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize='large')
```

You can also enter the `labelsize` as a float, or any of the following string options: 'xx-small', 'x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large', or 'xx-large'.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to changing the font size is to change the padding. When Python saves your PNG, you can change the layout using the dialogue box that opens. The spacing between the axes, padding if you like can be altered at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

Place `right_ax` before `set_ylabel()`

`ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('AB scale')`

Answer (score 0):

All of the "labeling" calls such as `suptitle()`, `set_xlabel()`/`plt.xlabel`, `set_title` etc. return a `matplotlib.text.Text` instance which define a `set_size()` method to adjust the fontsize. The ways to access these instances vary depending on what is wanted; `suptitle` can be accessed via `fig._suptitle`, while `xlabel` can be accessed via `ax.xaxis.label`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(2))
ax.set_title('Subplot title')   # Text(0.5, 1.0, 'Subplot title')
fig.suptitle('Figure title')    # Text(0.5, 0.98, 'Figure title')
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')         # Text(0.5, 0, 'xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')         # Text(0, 0.5, 'ylabel')

fig._suptitle.set_size(25)      # change figure title size
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)    # make space between subplots and figure

ax.xaxis.label.set_size(15)     # change xlabel size
ax.yaxis.label.set_size(15)     # change ylabel size
ax.title.set_size(15)           # change subplot title size
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score -4):

## libraries

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## create dataset

height = [3, 12, 5, 18, 45]

bars = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')

x_pos = np.arange(len(bars))

## Create bars and choose color

plt.bar(x_pos, height, color = (0.5,0.1,0.5,0.6))

## Add title and axis names

plt.title('My title')

plt.xlabel('categories')

plt.ylabel('values')

## Create names on the x axis

plt.xticks(x_pos, bars)

## Show plot

plt.show()

Comment: Welcome Tejas! Please consider formatting your answer to make it easier to read. Formatting some parts in [code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) would be a good start.

Answer (score -8):

## 7 (best solution)

```
 from numpy import*
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 X = linspace(-pi, pi, 1000)

class Crtaj:

    def nacrtaj(self,x,y):
         self.x=x
         self.y=y
         return plt.plot (x,y,"om")

def oznaci(self):
    return plt.xlabel("x-os"), plt.ylabel("y-os"), plt.grid(b=True)
```

## 6 (slightly worse solution)

```
from numpy import*
M = array([[3,2,3],[1,2,6]])
class AriSred(object):
    def __init__(self,m):
    self.m=m
    
def srednja(self):
    redovi = len(M)
    stupci = len (M[0])
    lista=[]
    a=0
    suma=0
    while a<stupci:
        for i in range (0,redovi):
            suma=suma+ M[i,a]
        lista.append(suma)
        a=a+1
        suma=0
    b=array(lista) 
    b=b/redovi
    return b



OBJ = AriSred(M)
sr = OBJ.srednja()
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: better use english.