# Label data when doing a scatter plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I want to label every dot I plot in python, and I didn't find a proper way to do it.

Assuming I have two lists of `n` elements called `a` and `b`, I print them this way :

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(a , b , 'bo')
    plt.show()
```

I want to label every point with "Variable k" with `k` ranging from `1` to `n` obviously.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the figure title and axes labels font size in Matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib)

Comment: ^^ That is setting names for axis'. I believe he wants to label every individual point.

Comment: What have you tried? Please, ***please*** read [ask] and [mcve]. Stack Overflow has very high quality standards.

Comment: You're right Dmitry Polonskiy that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best way of doing it I found :

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(a,b)
labels = ['Variable {0}'.format(i+1) for i in range(n)]
for i in range (0,n):
    xy=(a[i],b[i])
    plt.annotate(labels[i],xy)
plt.plot()
```

More infos : [Matplotlib: How to put individual tags for a scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `label` plot parameter

```
x = np.random.random(3)
y = np.random.random(3)
z = np.arange(3)
colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue"]
c = ["ro", "yo", "bo"]

for i in z:
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], c[i], label=colors[i] + ' ' + str(i))
plt.legend()
```

[image]