# Using matplotlib.pyplot, how can I label the largest data points for each line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a line graph with 3 lines. For each line, I would like to label just the largest data point. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Labeling points in matplotlib scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998205/labeling-points-in-matplotlib-scatterplot)

Comment: Note the duplicate that question is marked of has more answers as well, though the OP is trying to use `scatter` instead of `plot`, which I assume you're using (though effectively, most of the solutions are the same)