# How to add title and xlabel and ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to add title (and xlabel and ylabel) to plt.scatter(x,y,...) or plt.plot(x,y,...) directly without writing additional lines?

It is easy to add it when we use Series_name.plot in which we simply write Series_name.plot(...,title='name') but it does not work for me if I write: plt.scatter(...,title='name') or plt.plot(...,title='name')

[plt<<   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt]

I am using Python 3.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried already and possibly add a code snippet of what does not work as you expect.

Comment: Not necessarily an exact duplicate, but the things you need can be find easily by just googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the figure title and axes labels font size in Matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm curious to know if we can write all of that in the parenthesis of  plt.scatter()?

Comment: No, it's not possible to add the arguments to the `plt.scatter()` call.

Comment: But neither is it to use those arguments in `plot()`, can anyone report that `plt.plot(...,title='name')` is actually working?

Comment: plt.plot(...,title='name') does not work but Series_name.plot(...,title='name') works.

Comment: @shm Those two commands have nothing in common. One is a `matplotlib.pyplot` command the other is a `pandas.Series` command. In order to use pandas, you can of course plot a scatter plot via `Series_name.plot(kind="scatter", ...,  ,title='name')`, see [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From the documentation of [`plt.scatter()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) there is no such arguments to set the title or labels.

But neither does the [`plt.plot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) command have such arguments. `plt.plot(x,y, title="title")` throws an error `AttributeError: Unknown property title`. So I wonder why this should work in either case.

In any case, the usual way to set the title is `plt.title`. The usual way to set the labels is `plt.xlabel`and `plt.ylabel`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= [8,3,5]; y = [3,4,5]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title("title")
plt.xlabel("x-label")
plt.ylabel("y-label")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's returning "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" for the line plt.title("title")

Answer (score 11):

It's as simple as adding:

```
plt.xlabel('your xlabel')
plt.ylabel('your ylabel')
plt.title('your title')
```

after the plt.scatter() command.
Then, write `plt.show()` to display the image with the labels and titles.
You may read about it more here: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html

Answer (score 9):

You cannot add title, xlabel, ylabel etc w/o additional lines but ***you can use a single additional line*** if you think this is better

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,5,3,2,4,7])
plt.gca().update(dict(title='SCATTER', xlabel='x', ylabel='y', ylim=(0,10)))
```

This approach has more sense if you want to apply the same attributes to a bunch of plots, because you can prepare in advance a dictionary to set all the parameters that you want to apply to each plot.

[image]

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you