# Matplotlib - how to use documentation to find specific needs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to be able to find specific setting/need in [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) using only it's site (docs) without web search etc. For example, I know wanted to change size of label of y-axis. I tried search on the site for `label size` and clicked top search result (not just because it was top, but is was about axes, not present term in search but exactly missing term of what I was looking for): https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html?highlight=label%20size.

There I was able to find `size` word for ticks only. It would be *strange* if the tool did not have option to change axis label size and web search found the solution: [How do I set the figure title and axes labels font size in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib) : `plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)`.

How can I find that solution (or some working other) via usage of Matplotlib docs site/tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic would be this: You identify which object you want to change. So in case of an axis label, you know that you can create such label via `plt.xlabel()` or `ax.set_xlabel()`. You therefore navigate to this function's/method's documentation page:
On the homepage you click on [`modules`](https://matplotlib.org/py-modindex.html) and then either on [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) or [`matplotlib.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#module-matplotlib.axes). In the list of functions/methods you scroll down to the function/method you're looking for.
Alternatively you can use the search for `xlabel` to arrive there.

In the docs of that method you find which parameters are allowed. It says

> Other Parameters:  `**kwargs` : [Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties
>               [Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties control the appearance of the label.

You click on [Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) and find a list of parameters. You go through them and identify that `fontsize` will likely be the parameter that sets the fontsize.