# Comprehensively setting matplotlib font parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib

From what I understand of [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) `matplotlib` provides 3 ways to change the style parameters for plotting (things like `axes.grid`). Those ways are: using style sheets to set many parameters at a time; setting specific parameters through `matplotlib.rcParams` or `matplotlib.rc`; or using a `matplotlibrc` file to set defaults.

I would like to understand if *all* of the parameters are accessible in each of the methods I listed above and where I can find a comprehensive list of *all* of the parameters.

I have tried to understand this from the linked documentation, but I often fail. A specific example is setting the axis font. I typically use a combination like this:

```py
axis_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'32'}
ax.set_ylabel('some axis title',**axis_font)
```

But it is not clear what `matplotlib` parameter (if any) I have set. Does there exist a parameter for the axis font that could be included in a style file for example?

Other attempts in my code include confusing blocks like:

```py
legend_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'22'}
#fonts global settings
matplotlib.rc('font',family=legend_font['fontname'])
```

By the names it seems like it would be changing the legend font, but actually it is clearly setting the parameter for the overall font. And the size is not being used. Are there `matplotlib` parameters for *specifically* the legend font and legend size?

The things I've tried are:

- Checking the example `matplotlibrc` at the bottom of the linked page (no sign of axis or legend fonts specifically)
- Printing `matplotlib.rcParams` (no sign of axis or legend fonts)
- Checking the [axis api](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#module-matplotlib.axes) (could not match up with example style files e.g. the [*classic* predefined style file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle) has `facecolor` set, which is mentioned in that page, but it also has `edgecolor` set which is not mentioned on the page)

Comment: `rcParams` is simply a dictionary of defaults that were deemed useful to allow to be set as defaults.  There is no guarantee that any particular method has an entry int he rcParams, and they should not be considered synonymous with the kwargs for various classes or methods.

Comment: If you want to change the legend font, suggest you use `ax.legend(prop=fontprop)`, rather than togging the rcParam.  Similarly, for axis fonts...

Comment: @JodyKlymak Ok. If I understand what you are saying this implies a very simple answer to my direct questions. i.e. No, the axis and legend fonts cannot be set by `rcParams` If this is the answer, please post it.

Comment: [This page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) and particularly the [sample rc file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) should be helpful.

Comment: @WilliamMiller I specifically referenced both of those pages in my answer. No, they did not answer this question for me.

Comment: All the rcParams are in the file that you linked.

Comment: Then perhaps you aren't looking closely enough, the answers to every part of this question are contained in that page. It is specifically helpful to look at the sample rc file because it contains a comprehensive list of **every** parameter which can be modified using `rcParams`, a `matplotlibrc` file, or a style sheet. And yes, you can modify the same set of parameters with any of the three methods.

Comment: You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib/59169442#59169442) helpful since it addresses how to change the legend font size specifically.

Comment: @WilliamMiller Thank you, but I **still** don't see any mention of how to change the font. I see how to change the sizes. Please, make this simpler for me--just tell me the parameter that specifies the font (like Arial) for the axis label. I am reading more carefully now, but you can easily save me time if you have the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rcParams` property which changes the font is `font.family` it accepts `'serif'`, `'sans-serif'`, `'cursive'`, '`fantasy'`, and `'monospace'` as outlined in the linked [sample `matplotlibrc` file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file). If `text.usetex` is `False` it also accepts any concrete font name or list of font names - which will be tried in the order they are specified until one works.

This method applies the specified font name to the entire figure (and to all figures when done globally). If you want to modify the font family for an individual `Text` instance (i.e. an axis label) you can use [`matplotlib.text.Text.set_family()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_family) (which is an alias for [`matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontfamily()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontfamily))

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ylabel = plt.ylabel("Y Label")
ylabel.set_family("DejaVu Serif")
plt.xlabel("X Label")

plt.show()
```

[image]

And to set the font family for just a legend instance you can use `plt.setp`, e.g.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

ylabel = plt.ylabel("Y Label")
plt.xlabel("X Label")
ylabel.set_family("DejaVu Serif")

legend = plt.legend(handles = [mpatches.Patch(color='grey', label="Label")])
plt.setp(legend.texts, family="EB Garamond")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Note that this method will not work when `text.usetex` is `True`.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. It seems to me that this implies that the axis and legend font _cannot_ be set individually with a style sheet (for example). You can instead set an overall font. Then you can change things for a specific object like the `ylabel` just before plot time. Similarly can change legend with call to `matplotlib.pyplot.setp` just before plot time. I'm interested to know if there are other aspects of the plot that cannot be set globally (once) with a stylesheet or similar--I enjoy a uniform style for the plots, so I would like to set it once and never change.

Comment: @villaa You are correct in the conclusion that the font family for individual text instances **cannot** be set with a style sheet, only the global font family. If you want to "*set it once and never change it*" and need different fonts for axis labels, legend, etc then I would suggest writing a function which wraps the individual generation function (e.g. `plt.xlabel()`) and responds to a custom parameter for setting the font family.

Comment: Ok, add that to the answer please. I will accept this as the best answer.