# x- y-labels not working in Google Colab Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, google-colaboratory

I want to plot a graph using `matplotlib` in Google Colab. In general, the graph looks fine except that I couldn't add a label to the `x-` or `y-axis`. I added some extra steps in the plot, so I'm not sure if that's why the plot is not working properly.

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data.csv', sep=',')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01')
df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > start_date) &
              (df['timestamp'] < end_date)]

ID = 3
df = df[df['id'] == ID]

df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in df['timestamp']] 

df.plot(x='timestamp', y='data', figsize=(10, 6),) 
plt.axhline(y=40, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=25, color='b', linestyle='-')

df['top_lim'] = 40
df['bottom_lim'] = 25

plt.fill_between(df.index, df['bottom_lim'], df['data'],
                where=(df['data'] >= df['bottom_lim'])&(df['data'] <= df['top_lim']),
                facecolor='orange', alpha=0.3)

mask = (df['data'] <= df['top_lim'])&(df['data'] >= df['bottom_lim'])
plt.scatter(df.index[mask], df['data'][mask], marker='.', color='black')

cumulated_time = df.index[mask].diff().sum()
plt.title(f'Cumulative time in range = {cumulated_time}')
plt.ylabel('data', fontsize=18)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Here is what the graph looks like:

[image]
It seems the x-label `timestamp` was already there initially, but not the `y-label`, and I couldn't change the `x-label` by inserting `plt.xlabel('data', fontsize=18)` as well.

I have tried out a few ways in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib) but nothing changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my xlabel cut off in my matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: @DizietAsahi Thank you for sharing the link - I tried the methodbut unfortunately nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problemam. maby you shuld try upgrade your libry

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I hope it works