# How to increase the fontsize of the title in plt.title()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I usually visualize my whole dataset to take a good look at all the features, before i do anything. The problem is that the font size of the title for each graph is so small that it is difficult to read. My three lines of codes with the result of them are in the image. Can someone help?

Thanks

[My code and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAruF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the figure title and axes labels font size in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Close it by making it as duplicate!