# How to set fontsize for title in pandas.DataFrame.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, bar-chart

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=['A','B','C'])
df['Name'] = ['Lily','Mary','Joan']
df.plot(x='Name', kind='barh', stacked=True, mark_right=True, figsize=(10,6),
        title='Distribution of Tags across Participants')
```

When I plot from a dataframe `df`. Can I tune the font size of the title? Passing a list/dictionary to the `title` argument instead of a string, perhaps? Basically I don't know how to integrate `matplotlib` functions into `df.plot()`.

Comment: df.plot allows all the functions present in `matplotlib`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444716/how-do-i-set-the-figure-title-and-axes-labels-font-size-in-matplotlib

Comment: https://realpython.com/pandas-plot-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can use `plt.title()` directly. [Tutorial](https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot)