# How to access axis label object in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add some text to a figure that I would like to align with the`xlabel`of the axes. I want to find the coordinates of the`xlabel`, but the function`ax.get_xlabel()`only returns the string displayed in the label.

How can I get access to the`xlabel`object (which I assume is just an instance of `text`) to find its coordinates, or is there some other means of obtaining them?

Comment: Pretty sure that's in the docs with examples.

Comment: @wwii well if you'd like to point me to where I could find it that would be great. The only functions I have found in the docs are `set_xlabel()` and `get_xlabel()` which only operate on the string value

Comment: Start at the beginning of the [Artist Tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html), there is a hint to your solution right at the beginning.  This is worth knowing if you want to have finer control over your Figures and/or you are going to be using matplolib a lot.

Comment: Ohhh, well now I feel stupid. I forgot that the "set" functions return a reference to the object. I also found I can get at it using `ax.xaxis.get_label()`. Thanks!

Comment: Quick search helps sometimes too, the (my) first result of a google search for "matplolib get xlabel position" turned up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290938/how-to-set-my-xlabel-at-the-end-of-xaxis

Comment: @wwii I saw that one (and several others) before posting, but it seems I missed the clues in the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an object in Python Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102423/getting-an-object-in-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution is not to use `ax.get_xlabel()`, but:

```
xlbl = ax.xaxis.get_label()
```

Or as wwii pointed out, just save a reference to the label when creating it. Embarrasingly simple.

```
xlbl = ax.set_xlabel(...)
```

and to obtain the coordinates:

```
xlbl.get_position()
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It answers the question.

Comment: you might get downvoted (not me), because your answer does not show *how exactly* you now get the coordinates (which is what you asked). maybe you could show how you extract the coordinates from `xlbl` (to get an upvote, maybe show how to change them subsequently)

Comment: Thanks @Schorsch, I guess the way I worded my question makes it sound that way. The emphasis was intended to be on finding the object since I already knew how to obtain its coordinates. I'll add it for completeness, but I still don't think that the downvote was justified.