# Change legend's title fontsize in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to change the fontsize of the title of my legend in `matplotlib`. Here's my first guess

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca()
ax.plot(range(10))
lg  = ax.legend(['test entry'],title='test')
lg.set_title(fontsize='large')
plt.show()
```

which produces the error

```
    File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    lg.set_title(fontsize='large')
TypeError: set_title() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'
```

I also tried

```
lg  = ax.legend(['test entry'],title='test',title_fontsize='large')
```

which produces

```
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title_fontsize'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your Python and therefore `matplotlib` version you have to proceed differently. Your second code is working with the latest version (3.1.2 ). You're probably running on Python 2 with `matplotlib`2.2.4. As you can see in the [API documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.4/api/legend_api.html) for this version there is no keyword argument for changing the legend's title size. You need to proceed like so :

```
lg.set_title('title',prop={'size':'large'})
```

---

## Matplotlib 2.2.4

With Python 2 version of `matplotlib` you're stuck with

```
plt.legend.set_title('title',prop={'size':'large'})
```

## Matplotlib 3.x.x

In the latest versions you have many options as

```
plt.legend.set_title('title',prop={'size':'large'})
```

or

```
plt.legend(...,title='title',title_fontsize='large')
```

or

```
plt.rcParams['legend.title_fontsize'] = 'large'
```

if you want to change the font size globally.

---

Here are some similar questions for more information :

- [How to set font size of Matplotlib axis Legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402561/how-to-set-font-size-of-matplotlib-axis-legend)
- [Changing font size of legend title in Python pylab rose/polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947167/changing-font-size-of-legend-title-in-python-pylab-rose-polar-plot)

Comment: Indeed I'm using Python 2. Thanks, very helpful.